# Dividing an inline form into columns based on model field value in django admin

Tags: layout, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I'm setting up an an admin page that handles the storage of data of a product, in this case it is shoes which most of you might realize usually comes in pairs of left and right. The shoes have a differing number of fields and that's why i've implemented an eav system where the forms for the shoes are contained in an inline.

All i would like to do now is to group the forms in the inline in two columns depending on the value of the field shoe_side (can be 'L' or 'R' for left and right)

This is regarding the change view since the system is set up so that it creates all the neccessary fields depending on another model we can call a product recipe.

I did this in javascript with templates before in a similar situation but that was without the inline fields so it's not applicable. I think if I could just group the fields of the two columns into two formsets I could edit the template to get the needed layout but I don't know if one can create formsets based on a field in the model, I haven't really grasped the concept of formsets.

```py
# The inline model
class Component(models.Model):
    part_name=models.ForeignKey(PartRecipe)
    shoe_side=models.CharField(choices=[('L', "Left"),('R', "Right")
    product_id = ForeignKey(ProductModel)
....

# The 'parent' model
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    product = ForeignKey(Productrecipe)
    ....
    # a lot of not relevant fields

# The admin classes
class ComponentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    template = 'admin/componentinline/stacked.html'
    model = Component
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [ComponentInline,]
```